# The logic behind WPF's GetLayoutClip()

Tags: c#, wpf

As I understand it, GetLayoutClip (as called from the static class LayoutInformation) will produce a Geometry outside of which the layout in WPF will clip a UIElement (except, of course, if the UIElement is one in which clipping is off by default - such as Canvas). To understand the logic better, I've tried to experiment with it using Grid but I'm getting some results I find to be a bit strange. I've used the following code to experiment.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSolution.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="216" Height="139" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
</Window>
```

and in the code-behind:

```
private Grid panel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel = new Grid();
        panel.Margin = new Thickness(0,70,10,0);
        panel.Width = 150;
        panel.Height = 100;
        panel.ClipToBounds = true;
        Content = panel;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine(panel.DesiredSize);
        Debug.WriteLine(panel.RenderSize);
        Debug.WriteLine(LayoutInformation.GetLayoutClip(panel).Bounds);
    }
```

Notice that I'm forcing ClipToBounds. Unsurprisingly, GetLayoutClip returns a Rectangle = (0,0,150,30), which makes complete sense; the geometry begins at the origin of the GridPanel and clips everything below the window and outside the width of the Grid (including whatever would overflow into the margin on the right).

However, if we turn off ClipToBounds, the Rectangle becomes (-20,0,190,30). Ok, so -20 sort of makes sense to me; relative to the origin of the Grid that gets you to the edge of the window on the left hand side. 0 also makes sense, as that's 70 from the top and exactly where the Grid begins in Y-direction. Why 190 width though? The Grid itself terminates at 170 and at 180 including the margin on the right. There's nothing that naturally ends at 190. Why 190?

Comment: If -20 makes sense to you, then 190 should also make sense, because it means a width where 20 is added to the left and to the right, i.e. 20+150+20.

Comment: @Clemens Well not really. -20 would simply define the Geometry to begin at the origin in X-direction of the parent container, while 190 in positive X-direction ends up in the middle of nowhere (i.e. the Grid doesn't end there, nor does the Grid plus its margin). Still though, I see your point that it at least adds up. Doesn't make much sense though in terms of the definition of the clipping region.

Comment: How that? I don't see any left margin of 20 anywhere. I guess the Grid's Margin is irrelevant anyway.

Comment: To your first point, WPF will try to align the Grid at center I believe, and that's why you get the -20 from the Grid to the Window. Still can't figure out the 190 though.

Comment: 190 is the width of the rectangle, not the right bound. Adding 20 to the left and to the right of a rectangle of width 150 results in 20+150+20 = 190.

Answer (score 0):

When `panel.ClipToBounds = true` then the clipped area is restricted by the bounds of the Grid. However, when you set it to 'false', then it is possible for the content to appear to the left or right side of your panel with negative margin. So the whole width of the window is taken as a clip rectangle. Since your grid is placed in the middle of the window and has -20 offset from the left edge, then the width of the rectangle is:

```
width = 216 - 20 - 3 - 3 = 190.
```

Where 3 is the size of the window border.